# SDR (system of distinct representatives) from Venn Diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I want to learn what is SDR (system of distinct representatives) today.

SDR (system of distinct representatives):

> SDR = System of distinct representatives. Given a finite family of
>   sets X={S1,…,Sn}, a system of distinct representatives, or SDR, for
>   the sets in X is a set of distinct elements x1,…,xn with xi belongs to
>   Si for 1≤i≤n.

And my textbook said me that:

> Let M1,M2, ... ,Mk be non-empty sets. System of distinct
>   representatives for M1,M2, ... ,Mk is a sequence of distinct
>   elements (m1,m2, ... ,mk ), such that mi∈Mi for i = 1, 2, ... ,k.

I didn't understand what it is? After that, i said to myself lets look at the examples.

[image]

This is the example. How can they do that? Or any futher reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is from your textbook, then you should ditch the textbook and find another. The problem statement

> Find the distinct representatives for the given system.

does not make any sense -- there's no such thing as "THE distinct representatives" of a family of sets. Instead there are (usually) many *different* possible choices of distinct representatives, which are all equally good. The image shows *one* of them, but it is not the only solution.

It's really a pretty simple concept -- just choose some element of each set to represent it, such that no element is used to represent two different sets at the same time. In the example from your image, you might use $x_2$ to represent $M_1$ and $x_4$ to represent $M_2$, or the other way around -- but you can't have $x_2$ represent both $M_1$ and $M_2$, nor can you choose to let $x_3$ represent $M_2$ because $x_3\notin M_2$.

Comment: I am an Erasmus Student because of that our textbooks are limited in this university. There is just one example but I understand the concept thank you :)